# Subdomain routing for parked domains

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I trying to use [Subdomain Route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) in Laravel 5.3 but I have problem for parked domains, How can I route all parked domains wildcard to controllers?
I have more than 8 domains which parked on my primary domain.

Should I create a new `route` for each domains ?

This is my code :

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'my.domain.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'UserDashboardController@index');
});
Route::group(['domain' => 'my.domain.us'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'UserDashboardController@index');
});
Route::group(['domain' => 'my.domain.uk'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'UserDashboardController@index');
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'store.domain.uk'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'SimpleShopController@index');
});
```